# How to manually chose the points plot with ListPlot, from a large dataset that is not uniform?

Tags: plotting, data

I have a list of the form

```
    data={{0.5, 3.14026}, {0.525, 3.13121}, {0.55, 3.1222}, {0.575, 
  3.11323}, {0.6, 3.10429}, {0.625, 3.0954}, {0.65, 3.08654}, {0.675, 
  3.07772}, {0.7, 3.06894}, {0.725, 3.0602}, {0.75, 3.0515}, {0.775, 
  3.04284}, {0.8, 3.03421}, {0.825, 3.02563}, {0.85, 3.01708}, {0.875,
   3.00857}, {0.9, 3.0001}, {0.925, 2.99168}, {0.95, 2.98329}, {0.975,
   2.97493}, {1., 2.96662}, {1.025, 2.95835}, {1.05, 2.95011}, {1.075,
   2.94192}, {1.1, 2.93376}, {1.125, 2.92565}, {1.15, 
  2.91757}, {1.175, 2.90953}, {1.2, 2.90153}, {1.225, 2.89357}, {1.25,
   2.88565}, {1.275, 2.87777}, {1.3, 2.86993}, {1.325, 
  2.86212}, {1.35, 2.85436}, {1.375, 2.84663}, {1.4, 2.83895}, {1.425,
   2.8313}, {1.45, 2.82369}, {1.475, 2.81612}, {1.5, 2.80859}, {1.55, 
  2.79365}, {1.6, 2.77888}, {1.65, 2.76426}, {1.7, 2.7498}, {1.75, 
  2.7355}, {1.8, 2.72135}, {1.85, 2.70736}, {1.9, 2.69351}, {1.95, 
  2.67981}, {2., 2.66626}, {2.05, 2.65284}, {2.1, 2.63957}, {2.15, 
  2.62644}, {2.2, 2.61345}, {2.25, 2.60059}, {2.3, 2.58787}, {2.35, 
  2.57528}, {2.4, 2.56282}, {2.45, 2.55048}, {2.5, 2.53828}, {2.55, 
  2.5262}, {2.6, 2.51424}, {2.65, 2.5024}, {2.7, 2.49069}, {2.75, 
  2.47909}, {2.8, 2.46761}, {2.85, 2.45624}, {2.9, 2.44499}, {2.95, 
  2.43385}, {3., 2.42282}, {3.125, 2.39573}, {3.25, 2.3693}, {3.375, 
  2.34351}, {3.5, 2.31835}, {3.625, 2.29378}, {3.75, 2.2698}, {3.875, 
  2.24639}, {4., 2.22352}, {4.125, 2.20119}, {4.25, 2.17938}, {4.375, 
  2.15806}, {4.5, 2.13723}, {4.625, 2.11688}, {4.75, 2.09698}, {4.875,
   2.07753}, {5., 2.05851}, {5.125, 2.03991}, {5.25, 2.02172}, {5.375,
   2.00393}, {5.5, 1.98652}, {5.625, 1.96949}, {5.75, 
  1.95282}, {5.875, 1.93651}, {6., 1.92054}, {6.125, 1.90491}, {6.25, 
  1.88961}, {6.375, 1.87462}, {6.5, 1.85995}, {6.625, 1.84557}, {6.75,
   1.8315}, {6.875, 1.8177}, {7., 1.80419}, {7.125, 1.79095}, {7.25, 
  1.77798}, {7.375, 1.76526}, {7.5, 1.7528}, {7.625, 1.74058}, {7.75, 
  1.7286}, {7.875, 1.71685}, {8., 1.70534}, {8.125, 1.69404}, {8.25, 
  1.68296}, {8.375, 1.6721}, {8.5, 1.66144}, {8.625, 1.65099}, {8.75, 
  1.64073}, {8.875, 1.63066}, {9., 1.62078}, {9.125, 1.61109}, {9.25, 
  1.60157}, {9.375, 1.59223}, {9.5, 1.58307}, {9.625, 1.57407}, {9.75,
   1.56523}, {9.875, 1.55655}, {10., 1.54803}, {11., 1.48512}, {12., 
  1.43045}, {13., 1.38275}, {14., 1.34098}, {15., 1.30427}, {16., 
  1.27192}, {17., 1.24334}, {18., 1.21802}, {19., 1.19554}, {20., 
  1.17555}, {21., 1.15774}, {22., 1.14185}, {23., 1.12764}, {24., 
  1.11493}, {25., 1.10355}, {26., 1.09334}, {27., 1.08417}, {28., 
  1.07594}, {29., 1.06853}, {30., 1.06187}, {32., 1.05048}, {34., 
  1.04122}, {36., 1.03369}, {38., 1.02755}, {40., 1.02254}, {42., 
  1.01845}, {44., 1.01511}, {46., 1.01238}, {48., 1.01014}, {50., 
  1.00831}, {55., 1.00506}, {60., 1.00308}, {65., 1.00188}, {70., 
  1.00115}, {75., 1.0007}, {80., 1.00043}, {85., 1.00027}, {90., 
  1.00018}, {95., 1.00013}, {100., 1.00012}}
```

I want to plot my data with in the interval 0 to 60. So, I use

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 60}, {0, 4}}]
```

However, as I have many points in the interval 0-10, the dots of `ListPlot` agglutinate in such interval. How can I overcome such agglutination without having to erase some points manually? Is there a way to choose which points to plot and which ones to exclude? Lets say I want the dots to be separated be a distance of 2, or 3, or whichever I see fits best.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does `ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> {100}, MeshFunctions -> {#&}, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[1,ColorData[97][1]], PlotStyle->None]` or  `ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> {100}, MeshFunctions -> {Piecewise[{{#,#>=20}},.5#]&}, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[1,ColorData[97][1]], PlotStyle->None]` something close to what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
ListPlot[DeleteDuplicates[data, EuclideanDistance[##] < 1.2 &]]
```

[image]

Connecting the dots might be appropriate in some cases:

```
ListLinePlot@data
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is that I'm also plotting other variables, so I need to distinct between one and the other. Therefore, `ListLinePlot` does not do the trick.

Comment: Well I did say “in some cases.” BTW, ListLinePlot can distinguish variables. What about the first solution which is the principal answer to the question you asked? You did not comment on it

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very tricky and useful first solution! Could you please explain in more detail the use of slotsequence inside `DeleteDuplicates[data, EuclideanDistance[##] < eps & ]`. I would have expected two arguments?? Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `SlotSequence[]` stands for `#1, #2` in this case.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, that's understood. And `#1,#2` are pairs of listelement of data?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Each argument of the *test* of `DeleteDuplicates`, such as `#1`, stands for an element of `data` at level 1. So in the case of the OP's data, `#1` represents a list of two coordinates. Same for `#2`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ...and all possible pairings of the points are considered! Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100049/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-ulrich-neumann).

Answer (score 2):

To get a different perspective

```
ListLogLinearPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 60}, {0, 4}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I want to keep the real scale, as I'm plotting against another functions and other Lists. I have other two Lists, and three functions. My other lists, also have similar issues as they have many points in the inner interval (0.5-10). I want to distinct between them, so they may be distinguishable even if they are printed in a grayscale. Only using `Dashing` is not doing the job done, because some of them overlap